# Proving $ \int_0^{+\infty} \frac{\sin(t)^{^{2n+1}}}{t} \, dt= \frac{\pi (2n)!}{2^{2n+1}(n!)^2} $ with elementary calculus?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals

Time ago I asked how to integrate this, but people answered me with advanced topics, so I have this doubt, is it possible to integrate this with elementary calculus?

$$ \int_0^{+\infty} \frac{\sin(t)^{^{2n+1}}}{t} \, dt= \frac{\pi (2n)!}{2^{2n+1}(n!)^2} $$

Comment: Do you know that for any $m\in\mathbb{N}^+$ we have $$\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin(m t)}{t}\,dt=\frac{\pi}{2}$$ ? If so, just write $\sin(t)^{2n+1}$ as a linear combination of objects like $\sin(mt)$. Easy win.

Comment: $\sin(t)=\frac{e^{it}-e^{-it}}{2i}$ and $\sin(mt)=\frac{e^{mit}-e^{-mit}}{2i}$ can be pretty useful for such a task.

Comment: I do not think repeated IBP will get you very far, as either choice results in a pretty difficult integral to evaluate. You're best bet is to write sine in terms of complex exponentials and go from there, you'll want to remember the binomial theorem for that.

Comment: And if you don't know the integral above, start with [Dirichlet's integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_integral) and do a chang eof variable.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

By the binomial theorem:
$$ \sin(t)^{2n+1} = \frac{(-1)^n}{4^n}\sum_{k=0}^{n}(-1)^k\binom{2n+1}{k} \sin((2n+1-2k)t)$$
hence
$$ \int_{0}^{+\infty}\left(\sin t\right)^{2n+1}\frac{dt}{t} = \frac{\pi(-1)^n}{2\cdot 4^n}\sum_{k=0}^{n}(-1)^k \binom{2n+1}{k} $$
and by recalling that $\sum_{k=0}^{2n+1}(-1)^k\binom{2n+1}{k}=\sum_{k=0}^{2n}(-1)^k\binom{2n}{k}=0$ and invoking $\binom{2n+1}{k}=\binom{2n}{k}+\binom{2n}{k-1}$ and the symmetry of binomial coefficients, we have that 
$$ \sum_{k=0}^{n}(-1)^k \binom{2n+1}{k}=(-1)^n\binom{2n}{n}, $$
so
$$ \int_{0}^{+\infty}\left(\sin t\right)^{2n+1}\frac{dt}{t} = \frac{\pi}{2^{2n+1}}\binom{2n}{n} $$
as claimed.

Comment: Funnily, the LHS is relatively similar to [Wallis' integrals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallis%27_integrals), and the RHS is exactly their value (but for even exponent). I don't know if it's possible to find a direct relationship.

Comment: WOW!, Thanks, this is pretty amazing, I've been trying for a lot of time by IBP,I'm really amazed

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut: the direct relation is given by the residue theorem, but I guessed the OP wanted to avoid it.

Comment: Ah, thanks. I'll have a look at this ;-)

Comment: Ok, the comments in the main question help.

Comment: It's a good exercise to show the first two lines, lots of fumbling around with finite sums. I wish this didn't require the use of knowing $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sin{(nt)}}{t} dt = \frac{\pi}{2}$, $n \in \mathbb{N}$, as that itself could be another post.